What to put for Handler in PyCharm AWS Toolkit Create Lambda function?
Using pycharm 2024.1.2 and python 3.9 and the AWS Toolkit. I'm trying to create a new lambda function from the toolkit. I right click on Lambda and select Create New AWS Lambda. The problem is, no matter what I put in the Handler field, I get the error "Must be able to locate the handler in the project in order to deploy to Lambda".
My directory structure is simply the root folder 'blah' and directly inside is my python file 'test_file' which has handler name 'lambda_handler'. No matter what I put for the handler I get the error mentioned. I've tried 'test_file.lambda_handler', 'lambda_handler', 'blah.test_file.lambda_handler' and nothing gets recognized and hence I can't create the function.
What can I do to resolve this so I can create a Lambda function through the AWS Toolkit?
